# How to remove PointLight after a certain amount of time has passed

Tags: libgdx, box2d, delay, timing, light

In my game, the character can shoot bullets and each time a bullet is shot, a muzzle flash will be created next to his gun. The muzzle flash is a box2d PointLight. Here's the relevant code for shooting:

```
    if (MRInput.isPressed(MRInput.BUTTON2)) {
          PointLight muzzle = new PointLight(handler, 500, new 0.1f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1), 10 / 100,
          player.getPosition().x + (30 / 100), player.getPosition().y);
    }
```

Should I make an array of muzzle flashes and remove them in game render loop after a certain amount of time has passed or could this be done in a simpler way in the inputhandler (which of course updates all the time) already?

I'm kind of lost with timing events, so any suggestions and examples of how to approach this problem would be very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

1) Declared these fields in my Game class:

```
private float muzzleTime;
private boolean muzzleTimeRunning;
```

2) Added these declarations to my shooting action described in the original question:

```
muzzleTime = 0
muzzleTimeRunning = true;
```

3) Added this to my game's update() method:

```
        if (muzzleTimeRunning == true) {
            muzzleTime += dt;
            if (muzzleTime >= 0.01f) {
                muzzle.remove();
                muzzleTimeRunning = false;
            }
        }
```